# Enterprise Architect Create an Installation Wizard for a Custom Toolbox

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I created my custom toolbox in Sparx Enterprise Architect using MDG technology, and I want to share and install this toolbox among my colleague's machines.

How to can create an installation wizard can be used as a setup file of my toolbox?

Comment: Just share the MDG. You can't just share a toolbox.

Comment: I know that, and I did it; however, I have icons and images of my own elements all of them not well copied on other machines, I found something similar to that which is called SGAM and RAMI toolbox in this link 
https://www.en-trust.at/downloads/rami-4-0-toolbox/rami-4-0-toolbox-download/  

The above toolbox lets users install all the elements with its images and icons easily using a setup wizard and that what I want

Comment: The reason they sell this product is that there is no cheap out-of-the-box installation for MDG Techs if you have images.

Comment: @ThomasKilian cant you export images with mdg?

Comment: yes, the images do not export with the MDG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of *installing* your MDG for other users.

1. If you have a single central model the easiest way is to import it into the model. That will make it available to all users of the model. Go to **Resources**, right click **MDG Technologies** and select the option **Import MDG Technology**
2. If you want to install it per user go to the MDG Technologies page and click on the **Advanced** button. This will allow you to enter either an url or a file path to the MDG file. Put your MDG file at the logication you specify here. This process will have to be repeated for each user who needs to use your MDG, but can be automated by figuring out the specific registry keys that store this information and using some kind of enterprise software distribution system to push the registry settings to all users. Edit the key **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\OPTIONS\MDGTechnology PathList** if you want to use this method.